# How to create certificate object using PKCS 11

Tags: c++, c, pkcs#11

I am currently working on a project using PKCS#11 to interact with an USB Token. I have read **PKCS #11 v2.20: Cryptographic Token Interface Standard** and I can create other objects using the `C_CreateObject` function, but when I create a Certificate with this code then the return code is always `CKR_DOMAIN_PARAMS_INVALID`. Can anybody tell my why I get this error? And if you have example in C or C++ please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'domain parameters' refers to the parameters associated with a cryptographic algorithm, such as DSA or Diffie-Hellman.

Does the USB token support the key lengths and algorithms used your certificate?

Were the domain parameters generated locally? Does the USB support externally provided domain parameters?

Without seeing any code, it's difficult to be more helpful.